# Instantiate a field variable

Tags: c#

This is a code snippet

```
public class CartItemList
{
    //internal list of items and the constructor that instantiates it
    private List<CartItem> **cartItems**;
    public CartItemList() {
        cartItems = new List<CartItem>();
```

I want to ask is it possible to launch **cartItems** list constructor before CartItemList() constructor instantiate it? and then just use default constructor of CartItemList?

Like this:

```
public class CartItemList
{
    //internal list of items and the constructor that instantiates it
    private List<CartItem> cartItems= new List<CartItem>();
    public CartItemList()
```

Comment: What's the problem? Did you even try run this code?

Comment: Also please note that this *isn't* Javascript, so shouldn't be tagged as a runnable Javascript code snippet. (I've edited the question to remove those tags and to format the code.)

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the comment you are right

Comment: the problem was that I wanted to ask a question you stupid, and because of your stupidity I can't ask any more

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a `class` (reference type) can have field initializers like that. The field initializer runs before the instance constructor.

If (and only if) you do not author any instance constructor yourself (and if the class is not static), the C# compiler will create one for you. It will be `public` (or `protected` in case of an `abstract` class) and will take zero arguments.

---

You can consider marking the field as `readonly` if it is to be only assigned to from the initializer and from the instance constructors. You can still `Add`, `Remove`, `Clear` etc. the `List<>`, but the instance will be fixed after constructors have exited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this as you've shown in your code and it will run before the constructor I believe.

I would go as far to say that this should be the recommended way, as sometimes people do forget to initialize field variables in constructors, but only when the situation calls for it.